# How to resize a picturebox without changing its middle coordinate

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

Unfortunately the picture box during resize jumps into the lower corner.
I read that I need to set something up with Docker and Anchor but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Location` (x, y) refers to the upper-left corner of the control.  When you resize the PictureBox, only the lower-right corner will move unless you also change the location.

Are you changing the size in code?  If so, you can use a helper method to do this.  The image needs to shift left by half of the change in width if it is getting bigger, and needs to shift right by half of the change of width if it is getting smaller (same logic applies to height):

```
private void ChangePictureBoxSize(int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    // these will be negative if picturebox is getting bigger
    int changeInWidth = pictureBox1.Width - newWidth; 
    int changeInHeight = pictureBox1.Height - newHeight;

    // will shift left and up if picturebox is getting bigger
    int newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + (changeInWidth / 2); 
    int newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + (changeInHeight / 2);

    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
}
```